# How to fix C2109:subscript requires array or pointer type

Tags: c

I'm having problem with some homework here. I'm totally newbie in programming, so anything should be helpful. I don't know how to fix C2109 error in C.
As you see, I have a `float` array that I have to sort, and look for the number `55.5`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

main() {
    float mr1[30], pom = 0;
    int i, indeks = -1, j, n, start, end, mid;
    printf("Enter length of array n<=30:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter numbers of array mr1:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%f", &mr1[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i <n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (mr1[i] > mr1[j]) {
                mr1[i] = pom;
                mr1[i] = mr1[j];
                mr1[j] = mr1[i];
            }
    }

    start = 0;
    end = n - 1;
    do {
        mid = (start + end) / 2
        if (mr1[mid] == 55.5) {
            indeks = mid;
        } else {
            if (mr1[mid] < 55.5) {
                start = mid + 1;
            } else {
                kraj = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    } while (poc <= kraj && indeks < 0);
    printf("Number 55.5 is on indeks:\n");
    printf("%d", indeks);
}
```

Comment: (1) You have missed a semicolon in the `mid=(start+end)/2` line. (2) You have not declared the variables `poc` and `kraj` anywhere.

Comment: `55.5` is a somewhat "nice" floating-point number. Comparing normal floating-point numbers with `==` is very likely to fail. You should avoid that.

Comment: And please check the return values from `scanf` - It returns a value for a reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the code:

- The swapping code is incorrect. It should read:

  ```
          pom = mr1[i];
          mr1[i] = mr1[j];
          mr1[j] = pom;
  ```
- you did not translate all `poc` as `start` and `kraj` as `end`.
- There is a missing `;` after `mid=(start+end)/2`
- `main()` is an obsolete prototype for the `main` function, you should specify the return type `int`.
- the `do` / `while` loop will not handle an empty array correctly. You should use a `while` loop instead. As a rule of thumb, `do` / `while` loop are very often incorrect, sometimes in subtile ways.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float mr1[30];
    int n, i, j, index, start, end, mid;

    printf("Enter length of array n<=30:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0 || n > 30) {
        printf("invalid length\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter numbers of array mr1:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%f", &mr1[i]) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    /* sort the array with simplistic swap sort */
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (mr1[i] > mr1[j]) {
                /* swap entries */
                float pom = mr1[i];
                mr1[i] = mr1[j];
                mr1[j] = pom;
            }
        }
    }

    /* try and locate 55.5 with binary search */
    index = -1;
    start = 0;
    end = n - 1;
    while (start <= end) {
        mid = (start + end) / 2;
        if (mr1[mid] == 55.5) {
            index = mid;
            break;
        } else {
            if (mr1[mid] < 55.5) {
                start = mid + 1;
            } else {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (index >= 0) {
        printf("Number 55.5 is at index %d\n", index);
    } else {
        printf("Number 55.5 is not present\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that `55.5` happens to have an exact representation as a `float`, but comparing floating point values with `==` may yield surprising results when the approximate value is not exactly identical to the expected value.